# NodeJS Async Database fetch server freezing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have an application running on NodeJS(express + mongoose + jade).
I have a post-route */search* (all routes are in a separate module) which should handle fetching data from mongo database and inserting it into jade template(in this case just printing th console):

```
router.post('/search', function (req,res) {

    var componentsArray = null;

    function getArray(){
        console.log('Initializing...');
        componentsArray = dataExchanger.search(req.body.select, req.body.selectType, req.body.searchField);
    }
    getArray(function () {
        console.log('Documents returned.');
        console.log('Printing array...');
        console.log('Array: ' + componentsArray);
        console.log('Array type: ' + typeof (componentsArray));
        console.log('Rendering page...');
        res.render('search_results');
    });
});
```

Searching and fetching function implemented in a different module *dataExchanger*:

```
exports.search = function(select, type, data) {
    console.log('Fetching documents...');
    componentsModel.find({name: data}, function (err, docs) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log('Returning documents...');
            return docs;
        } else {
            console.log('Can\'t return documents!');
            throw err;
        }
    });

};
```

**The problem is** that when I am using a callback function for *getArray()*, the server just freezes at the moment of *returning docs* and stops responding.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you executing the callback passed to getArray ?

Comment: I am passing anonymous function to it. Sorry, new to async functions. Can't figure out even after reading some articles.

Comment: You are passing it, but not executing it.

Comment: How should execution look like? Like getArray(callback) and then callback()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use async/await

```
router.post('/search', async (req,res) => {
  let componentsArray;

  try {
     componentsArray = await dataExchanger.search(req.body.select, req.body.selectType, req.body.searchField);
  } catch(e){
    //If error in request and no data.
    console.error('Error', e.message);
    return res.render('error_message');
  }

  console.log('Documents returned.');
  console.log('Printing array...');
  console.log('Array: ' + componentsArray);
  console.log('Array type: ' + typeof (componentsArray));
  console.log('Rendering page...');

  res.render('search_results');

});
```

And here is your dataExchanger

```
exports.search = function(select, type, data) {
   console.log('Fetching documents...');

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     componentsModel.find({name: data}, function (err, docs) {
       if(err) return reject(err);
       resolve(docs);
      });
   })
};
```

Further reading: [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Thanks! That's it! Going to get deeper into it.

Comment: Since Express doesn't handle promises, it's a good practice to wrap everything with try...catch...finally because otherwise it could result in pending request without errors (unhandled promise error at the very best).

Answer (score 0):

```
    router.post('/search', function (req,res) {

        var componentsArray = null;

        function getArray(cb){
            console.log('Initializing...');
            componentsArray = dataExchanger.search(req.body.select, req.body.selectType, req.body.searchField);
//Execute the callback    
cb();
        }
        getArray(function () {
            console.log('Documents returned.');
            console.log('Printing array...');
            console.log('Array: ' + componentsArray);
            console.log('Array type: ' + typeof (componentsArray));
            console.log('Rendering page...');
            res.render('search_results');
        });
    });
```

Looks like your search method is async as well, so you will need to pass the callback down to that to get the desired result.

Comment: Made it this way. Now the problem is that callback doesn't wait for returning the array. So it is called before the document returns now.